# place ID does not provide same category as google maps are using

Tags: android, google-places-api

As I am using the **Google Place API** for getting *supported types* but I didn't find the same as google maps are using. I am attaching one screenshot of the place, in google map category show co-working space but from API the category is Point of Interest.

Can anyone help to find this issue?

[image: Screenshot of Place]

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get place description from Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785672/how-to-get-place-description-from-google-places-api)

Comment: Thank you @xomena