# How can I get access to the "taglines" using the google places(or other) api?

Tags: google-api

When searching for a restaurant in Google maps a tagline underneath the restaurant name shows up. Example: Searching Taqueria Diana brings up underneath "Mexican food with a California bent". But when using the Google Places API a types list is all that shows up.

My question is not a duplicate of this question. [How to get place description from Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785672/how-to-get-place-description-from-google-places-api)

Please checkout the picture before marking duplicate. They are different.

[Google maps tagline example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yveKz.jpg)

This is not part of the Google API types.

Does anyone know how to get the tagline?