# Google Place API - How can i get the content of particular place by using place ID

Tags: android, google-places-api

I wanna to get the description / content based on `PLACE_ID` which parameter/key wanna to access the value from Google place API

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?
placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&fields=name,rating,formatted_phone_number,photo&key=KEY`

Tried above i got the value whatever i mentioned in filed but i want content for particular place by using place ID

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-id) and [this](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details)?

Comment: ya i checked the above..used all the field but couldnt able to get the content/description ...FYR"address_component,adr_address,alt_id,formatted_address,geometry,icon,id,name,permanently_closed,photo,place_id,plus_code,scope,type,url,utc_offset,vicinity"

Comment: That will be able to get in json response

Comment: How can i access the below rating of content from Google page..For Ex: Olympia theater under rating bar content is it possible to read any attribute to get that

Comment: @TracyAdams have you enable your google Places API in your account and have you done proper setup for key?

Comment: This description is not available via API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get place description from Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785672/how-to-get-place-description-from-google-places-api)