# Google Maps API not returning category from search

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to return the category or types from google maps api but getting inconsistent results.

The below shows correct types for 'lowes'.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=lowes&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,name,types&key=API_KEY

```
     "types" : [
        "hardware_store",
        "furniture_store",
        "home_goods_store",
        "point_of_interest",
        "store",
        "establishment"
```

However, when I try something like the below...
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Alaska%20Railroad%20Bogard&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,name,types&key=API_KEY

I get ...

```
     "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]
```

But when i just go to googlemaps.com and search for 'Alaska Railroad Bogard' I get the type or category as **'Railroad Company'**

I am looking to return **'Railroad Company'**

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get place description from Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785672/how-to-get-place-description-from-google-places-api)

Comment: looks like a duplicate. thx