# Google Places API: getting type of restaurant

Tags: google-places-api

I'm trying to get place infos from a restaurant and it works so far, the only data I'm missing is the type of restaurant: `Spanish Restaurant` which shows up in the actual Google Maps below the rating.
I googled for it and couldn't find it anywhere. Any ideas how it's called and how to retrieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get place description from Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785672/how-to-get-place-description-from-google-places-api)